# Display flash file with URL in UIWebView: Obj C/swift

Tags: ios, uiwebview, flashplayer-10

I have game URL-
https://nogs-gl.nyxinteractive.eu/game/?nogsgameid=70090&nogsoperatorid=268&nogscurrency=eur&nogslang=en_us&nogsmode=demo

URL is running well in my web browser.
I want to display this in my iOS app. Currently, I am doing that so by using native UIWebView but it's displaying the message as

[image]

What am I supposed to do for opening the given URL in my application?

Comment: Come on: really don't use flash... There are so many issues with it - you have to stay on time...

Comment: then what is the solution for that?

Comment: Just don't use flash: try to make the "About us" page with HTML, CSS and even JavaScript if you want.. You can also read through the internet about flash and it's disadvantages -- maybe someone is pointing to another alternative somewhere. But you have to bear in mind, that there is a reason why companies stop using flash and all modern browsers disable it by default: there are so many security issues with flash. And as you're currently developing a new app, just update (i.e. get away from flash) and use a more secure, reliable and stable technology.

Comment: Because of this reasons even apple disabled flash even in it's `UIWebView` as you are encountering....

Comment: sounds good, but the provided URL has a game demo and so many games are there that are already developed in flash, so instead of making all the game I am adding the flash files there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS does not support Flash. It never has, and it never will. You cannot run flash content on iOS.

Comment: any link which is explaining this?

Comment: Here's [Steve Jobs's explanation](https://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/), and here's [Adobe's discontinuation of support announcement for Mobile Flash](https://blogs.adobe.com/conversations/2011/11/flash-focus.html) from 2011

Comment: great, now what to do you think which option do I have to get this game implementation done?

Comment: is it possible with .swf file?

Comment: An `.swf` file is just a saved Flash file, so it cannot be run in an iOS browser by definition. I'm not familiar with Flash development, so I'm not particularly qualified to make this call, but I'd encourage a rewrite in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, but I found [this post on the Creative Cloud blog](https://blogs.adobe.com/creativecloud/what-to-expect-when-converting-flash-to-html5/) about what to expect